# Does every webserver have an httpd.conf file?

Tags: server, httpd.conf

I have spent my whole day finding the location of the *httpd.conf* file for my website. I contacted my host and they told me they didn't give us permission to modify the *httpd.conf* file.

Some webservers gives the permission to edit and find the *httpd.conf* file on their servers via ssh.

My question is that does every webserver have an *httpd.conf* file in their directory?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to review the Help Center's section on [Asking](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help) questions, and refrain from asking overly generalized questions (i.e., questions here should be specific and related to your website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*httpd.conf* is available only if you have Apache as the web server. Nginx and LiteSpeed have their own configuration files and names.

On cPanel servers it is under the `/usr` directory, whereas on plain servers with Linux distros, it is under the `/etc` directory.

Answer (score 2):

Not all servers use httpd.conf, but all have some type of configuration file. If you're using apache, the httpd.conf configurations can be overriden through .htaccess file in the root web directory unless overrides are turned off in httpd.conf

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

Comment: so every server has its own configuration files right ??? it can be httpd.conf or some other files right z??

Comment: Yes, all mainstream web servers will have some type of configuration file. The configuration controls the entire server, so in the case like yours it's probably a shared host so you'll have to use overrides through .htaccess . They can't allow you to change the main config file because it would impact the entire server.

Comment: If its a vps host will i will be able to find my httpd.conf file ?

Comment: If you can access the directory "/etc" on the server then you can probably access it the conf file. If your access is limited to the web directory then no.

Comment: No problem, you can put this in a php file to find out your current path on the server: echo realpath(dirname(__FILE__));  Then run the php file.